# How to open flash projector on a specific screen

Tags: windows, flash, batch-file, multiple-monitors

I am running two Flash projector applications in fullscreen mode and would like to open each one on a seperate screen. For security reasons I assume it is not possible to configure it directly in Flash. Are there any command line parameters I can use, or is it somehow possible to achieve it using a batch file (I am using Windows).

Comment: How do you do it currently?  Do you type a bunch of commands from the cmd prompt or do you click on a whole load of things to start it.

Comment: I just created two shortcuts on the desktop. By clicking it the application opens on the screen it is placed on.

Comment: What do those shortcuts do?  Are they shortcuts to applications or shortcuts to batch files.  What is in *Target* when you look at the shortcut properties?  If it is a shortcut to a batch file, what does the batch file look like?

Comment: They are simply shortcuts to the exe files without any additional parameters.